# How do you stop the DiaSession warning from TFS CI build when using NUnit?

Tags: continuous-integration, nunit

How do you stop the DiaSession warning from TFS CI build when using NUnit?

```
0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
Unable to create DiaSession for .... 
No source location data will be available for this assembly.
```

Comment: It is part of Nunit [TestConverter](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/blob/master/src/NUnitTestAdapter/TestConverter.cs) class, and they commented that they have issues with DiaSessions, so you get the warning. You may extend NUnit to remove warning or suppress the warning on msbuild [nowarn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7.aspx)?

Comment: Extending TestConverter class to give a specific error number, and supress in msbuild for that number may also work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use add the /p:NoWarn=warningNumber in **MSBuild Arguments** in the build definition. Or use the /p:WarningLevel=0 argument to suppress all warnings. 
[image]