# TFS Build 2015 "Warning: Unable to create DiaSession for..." NUnit

Tags: tfs, nunit, tfsbuild

When trying to run the unit tests as a build step in TFS Build 2015 (vNext), I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Unable to create DiaSession for <assembly>
No source location data will be available for this assembly.
```

The test assembly is then run, but the unit tests inside fail because they can't locate the references, I'm assuming because of the 'No source location data will be available' part of the warning.

The NUnit NuGet package I am using for the unit tests is: "NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework" v2.0.0. The project is made in C#.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548560/how-do-you-stop-the-diasession-warning-from-tfs-ci-build-when-using-nunit) question, but I don't really understand what they are saying, and it doesn't look like they are using TFS Build 2015 (vNext) build definitions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you referenced is talking about the old TFS build XAML not vNext build the one you  are using.

However you could also use the same MSBuild arguments in vNext Visual Stduio Build or MSbuild task.

> You need to use add the /p:NoWarn=warningNumber in MSBuild Arguments
>   in the build definition. Or use the /p:WarningLevel=0 argument to
>   suppress all warnings.

According to your error info, seems the issue should not related to TFS build side. Since unit tests inside fail because they can't locate the references, please try to directly run your tests on the build agent locally(remote to). This will help you to narrow down the issue.  Besides, also [Enable Verbose Debug Mode for TFS Build vNext](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) by adding `system.debug=true` to see if there are more details log info for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realize now that this is just a warning, and all the errors that came after this warning that I had were unrelated - therefore I'll mark your solution as the answer since it does solve the warning. Incase you're interested, it was me referencing the wrong version of the DLLs in a build step that caused the errors following this warning.